# What does the adjective "complicated" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read a sentence in my book which was:

> Their work led to a realisation that issues of injustice to women and of gender inequalities were complicated in nature.

The adjective "complicated" means "difficult to understand, analyse". But I don't think that is the sense the word has been used in here. So, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

In this context, "complicated" means that these inequalities were not easy to understand and explain. They were not simple, they were complicated, with many factors at play.